# How can I align labels and text fields added to a split pane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jsplitpane

In the below code I want to align my labels and text fields.in the left Pane. I have tried using `setBounds()` and `setLocation()` methods but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
package com.sample.GUI;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class GUI extends JFrame 
{  

    public void GUI(){
        JPanel leftPan = new JPanel(); 
        JPanel rightPan = new JPanel();
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPan,rightPan);
         
        JLabel l1,l2;  
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField();       
        JFilePicker filePicker = new JFilePicker("Select FIle", "Browse...");
        filePicker.setMode(JFilePicker.MODE_OPEN);
        String filePath = filePicker.getSelectedFilePath();
        rightPan.add(filePicker);
        l1=new JLabel("Label1");   
        l2=new JLabel("Label2");
        l2.setBounds(100,150, 100,30); 
        l2.setBounds(100,100, 100,30);  
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.6);
        splitPane.setDividerSize(1);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        getContentPane().add(splitPane, null);
        leftPan.add(l1);
        leftPan.add(l2);  
        leftPan.add(t1);
        leftPan.add(t2);
        setSize(700,500);  
        setTitle("GUI");
        setVisible(true); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   } 
}
```

Comment: *I have tried >using setBounds() and setLocation()* - you should NOT be using those methods. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager will set the size/location of each component on the panel depending on the rules of the layout manager. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples to download an experiment with. If you are trying to align vertically you could use a BoxLayout or GridBagLayout, or GridLayout or a combination of multiple layout managers.

Comment: 1) `JTextField t1 = new JTextField();` The layout managers mentioned by @camickr work better when the components they are laying out return a sensible preferred size. So that should be more like `JTextField t1 = new JTextField(n); // 'n' -> # of columns` 2)  Once using layout managers, `setSize(700,500);` can (& should) be replaced by `pack(); // <- not a guess`. 3) `String filePath = filePicker.getSelectedFilePath(); rightPan.add(filePicker);` That would not compile.

Comment: Ignore point 3. I mistook `filePicker` for the `String` based `filePath`. On that topic, what is a `FilePicker`? NVM For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) Your constructor is written like a method, no `void` needed. 2) `JFilePicker` is not a standard Swing component. Did you write that class yourself or did you use someone elses code? 3) As other commenters have mentioned, you should not be using `setBounds()` and `setLocation` to manage your layout, that's what layout managers are for. Interestingly enough, you must know that at least partially because you do set your layout to be a `GridBagLayout` but then never do anything with it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I'm guessing this is the JFilePicker that the OP is using.  It's a nifty Swing extension.  It's too bad that the OP couldn't follow the JFilePicker author's coding style.  https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/file-picker-component-in-swing

Comment: Here's the Oracle tutorial on How to Use The GridBag Layout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Grid Layout Helped

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Now you might simply delete the question, or enter an answer below our comments. But I'm up-voting the question based on you solving it with a few tips, so if you delete it, you may lose those reputation points.